# why your new clone didn't contain all changes

Tags: git

I have submitted several changeset to git responsitory and pushed up.

I can see my changeset in remote responsitory, but after I clone a new respository.

I cannot see the newest change on several files.
I only have one branch.

```
$ git branch
* master

$ git log
showing all the logs in the right way

$ git log <filename1> #look at certain file <p>
It does not show the newest change on that file

$ git log --full-history <filename1> <p>
It is showing the newest change on that file
```

I want my file pickup the newest change.

What I should do?

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between ´git log´ and ´git log --full-history´ is that the first form will hide certain entries if they don't really lead to the end result. I thought that it only effected branches but it might be what's hitting you.

You can read about this different in the [man pages](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) for `git log`

Does it feel like the end result in your two logs are the same or different?

Comment: The file's end result is in agree with "git log", but I want all changes that can apply to my file, which are the changes within "git log --full-history".

Comment: That is exactly the difference. `git log` may skip steps that doesn't lead to the end results. Read through the man pages and you'll find it there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and I have read the man, but I still want my file take all the changes. How can I make the file pickup all the changes and why my file did not take some of the changes?

Comment: Sorry, I read your question in the title about the difference between log and log --full-history. I never understood that you really wanted to ask about why your new clone didn't contain all changes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I really want is all changes be picked up by my new clone.

Answer (score 0):

When cloning a repository only a single branch is checked out, usually master. That is why your cloner repository list only `master`.

Try running `git branch --remotes`, it should display all the branches in the original repository.

About your missing changes, these could be in a different branch that `master`. If that is the case you just need to checkout the proper branch in which you where working:

```
git checkout origin/someBranch
```